Can't call Javascript on Safari through Applescript
I'm trying to determine if a tab is playing audio via javascript, which is being called by the following applescript:
tell application "Safari"
    set theScript to "!!Array.prototype.find.call(document.querySelectorAll('audio,video'),function(elem){return elem.duration > 0 && !elem.paused});"
    set ret to do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
    return ret
end tell

However, I get the following error:
error "The variable ret is not defined." number -2753 from "ret"
This javascript works fine when called through the Safari Console. I have tried investigating missing imports that are loaded in Console but not via the call from Applescript, but can't seem to solve this. Please could someone help me?
Edit:
Running the following works, so the problem lies with the specific javascript I am trying to run
tell application "Safari"
    set theScript to "numbervalue=3;fred=numbervalue+4"
    set ret to do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
    return ret
end tell

returns 7 as expected

theScript doesn't return anything.

@Barmar it does, it returns true or false, see https://imgur.com/a/Lzi0dRb (this was ran on the Safari Console). This script works when calling it via Chrome, but not Safari for some reason

@Barmar I have added an edit to the post, do you mind looking at it please? I think Safari has problem running this JS when Chrome does not - is there another way of achieving what I am trying to do with another JS script?

The console is a read-eval-print loop, it prints the value of the expression. But most other contexts require you to write return <value> for the value to be used.

@Barmar I managed to solve it - for some reason with Safari and do JavaScript, it fails to return boolean values. I had to use toString() to make it return properly

For some strange reason do JavaScript has trouble returning booleans, so after hours of trying things this ended up working:
tell application "Safari"
    set theScript to "a = !!Array.prototype.find.call(document.querySelectorAll('audio,video'),function(elem){return elem.duration > 0 && !elem.paused}); a.toString();"
    set ret to do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
    return ret
end tell

BUT this is only a problem when calling in Safari! Hope this helps a poor soul out
